# Why modal="true" in html file fail to compile in jhipster with PrimeNG?

Tags: java, html, jhipster, primeng

I have generated a jhipster application and has added PrimeNG into it using yo jhipster-primeng.
Everything work well. But when I want to run the application using ./mvnw, I got the following error in the PrimeNG .html file. As shown in the log below, the error said, type string is not assignable to type boolean. And if we go further down the list, the error is coming from .html file where there is
disabled="true".
In normal .html file, this has no problem. Why in this jhipster application, it become an error? Does anyone have any clue.
Is there a way or a setting to be done to ignore this kind of error?

Best regards,

Alvin.

Note: my jhipster version is 6.10.1
generator-jhipster-primeng is 9.1.0
java version is 11.0.6

```
[INFO]  ERROR  Failed to compile with 165 errors10:28:21 PM
[INFO] 
[INFO]  error  
[INFO] 
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/buttons/splitbutton/splitbuttondemo.component.html:30:78 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 30             <p-splitButton label="Create" icon="fa fa-check" [model]="items" disabled="true"></p-splitButton>
[INFO]                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO] 
[INFO]   src/main/webapp/app/primeng/buttons/splitbutton/splitbuttondemo.component.ts:6:18
[INFO]     6     templateUrl: './splitbuttondemo.component.html',
[INFO]                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component SplitbuttonDemoComponent.
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/overlay/dialog/dialogdemo.component.html:16:44 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 16             <p-dialog [(visible)]="custom" modal="true">
[INFO]                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO] 
[INFO]   src/main/webapp/app/primeng/overlay/dialog/dialogdemo.component.ts:6:18
[INFO]     6     templateUrl: './dialogdemo.component.html',
[INFO]                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component DialogDemoComponent.
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/overlay/dialog/dialogdemo.component.html:33:63 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 33             <p-dialog header="PrimeNG" [(visible)]="advanced" modal="true" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" responsive="true" closable="true" dismissableMask="true" rtl="true">
[INFO]                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO] 
[INFO]   src/main/webapp/app/primeng/overlay/dialog/dialogdemo.component.ts:6:18
[INFO]     6     templateUrl: './dialogdemo.component.html',
[INFO]                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component DialogDemoComponent.
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/overlay/dialog/dialogdemo.component.html:33:102 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 33             <p-dialog header="PrimeNG" [(visible)]="advanced" modal="true" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" responsive="true" closable="true" dismissableMask="true" rtl="true">
[INFO]                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]
```

Comment: Have you tried adding brackets around the HTML property? Otherwise, I think the value is stringified. For example, `[disabled]="true"`

Comment: thanks Jon. It work. I just need to put  square brackets on those. Is there any settings in compile option or whatever that can be done so that we do not have to perform this on this error?